# How do you calculate a monthly loan payment when using Actual/365 or Act/Act day count convention?

Tags: loans, interest, lending

It is pretty easy to figure out a monthly loan payment based on the standard formula, when using a 30/360 method, because the monthly interest rate is always the same since each month has 30 days.

But when using Act/Act you need to count the actual days in the month (28-31) and actual days in the year.  Is there another formula or standard method for figuring out the payment in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

No there is no such formula, you have to iterate through the computation.